# How to hide the space between cells in DHTMLX 3.0?

Tags: javascript, dhtmlx

I've created a '3T' layout in dhtmlx. And if I create the cells, there is a splitter, or some space between them. How is it possible, to remove the spacing from between cell "a" and "b"?

I know DHTMLX is not a well known library, that's why I can't find the answer on the internet.

Comment: are you trying to collapse the table cells?? if yes, css could help you to sove this `table {border-collapse: collapse;}`

Comment: only between two given DHTMLX cells (`a` and `b`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Layout's cell separators are hardcoded. They are inseparable visual and functional elements of layout's structure. Thus, they can't be removed or hidden.